alguien podria darme una mano con los links de mi NavBar con react-router-dom en React JS combinado con firebase?
<div className="dropdown-content">
                                        <Link to="/Catalogo">Todos los Productos</Link>
                                        {categorias.map(categoria => (
                                            <Link to={`/Catalogo/${categoria.id}`} key={categoria.id}>
                                                {categoria.nombre}
                                            </Link>
                                        ))}
                                    </div>

este es mi dropdown el cual quiero que tome los links de las categorias y cree sus respectivas paginas, en las cuales haré un menú con sus subcategorias correspondientes dentro del siguiente codigo:
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import SearchBar from "../components/Search/SearchBar";
import { collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { db } from '../firebase';
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';


const MainSubCategoria = () => {
    const { idSubCategoria } = useParams();
    const [subcategorias, setSubcategoria] = useState([]);
    const [categorias, setCategorias] = useState('');


    const getCategorias = async () => {
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, 'categorias'));
        const categoriasData = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }));
        setCategorias(categoriasData);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getCategorias();
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getSubcategorias = async () => {
            const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, 'categoMarca'));
            const subcategoriaData = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }));
            const productosBySubCategoria = subcategoriaData.filter(subcategoria => subcategoria.id === idSubCategoria);
            setSubcategoria(productosBySubCategoria);
        };

        getSubcategorias();
    }, [idSubCategoria]);


    if (!categorias) {
        return <h2> Categoria no Encontrada  </h2>
    } else {
        (
            <div>
                <Navbar />
                return (
                <div>
                    {categorias.map(categoria => (<h1>Categoría:{categoria.nombre} </h1>))}
                    <div>
                        {subcategorias.map(subcategoria => (
                            <Link to={`/Catalogo/${idSubCategoria}`} key={subcategoria.id}>
                                {subcategoria.nombre}
                            </Link>
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
                );
            </div>
        );
    };
};

export default MainSubCategoria;

mis ruteos con react-router-dom son los siguientes para que puedan guiarse de si proviene de alli el error, lo cual dudo que sea asi
import React from "react";
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import "./css/styles.css"
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Inicio from "./Pages/Inicio";
import Ofertas from "./Pages/Ofertas";
import Categorias from "./Pages/Categorias";
import Arribos from "./Pages/Arribos";
import ProductDetail from "./Pages/ProductDetail";
import { CartProvider } from "./components/Cart/CartContext";
import Formulario from "./Pages/Formulario";
import Cart from "./Pages/Cart";
import Nosotros from "./Pages/Nosotros";
import MainSubCategoria from "./Pages/MainSubCategoria";

function App() {
  return (
    <CartProvider>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Inicio />} />
          <Route exact path="/Catalogo" element={<Categorias />} />
          <Route exact path="/Ofertas" element={<Ofertas />} />
          <Route exact path="/Nosotros" element={<Nosotros />} />
          <Route exact path="/Arribos" element={<Arribos />} />
          <Route exact path="/Cart" element={<Cart />} />
          <Route exact path='/Catalogo/:products' element={<ProductDetail />} />
          <Route exact path="/Catalogo/:categorias" element={<MainSubCategoria />} />
          <Route exact path="/FormularioDeEnvio" element={<Formulario />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </CartProvider>
  );
}

export default App;

esta todo correctamente importado, no encuentro la falla dentro del codigo para solucionar, ya que toma la id de la categoria perfectamente pero no logra redigirme a su respectiva pagina, donde yo quiero hacer los enlaces a sus subcategorias... desde ya muchas gracias

Creo que tu problema yace en que usas 2 veces "Catalogo" en /Catalogo/:products y /Catalogo/:categorias y no puede diferenciar en cual mostrar. Te recomiendo cambiarlo a algo como:
  <Route exact path='/Catalogo/:products' element={<ProductDetail />} />
  <Route exact path="/Categoria/:categorias" element={<MainSubCategoria />} />


Muchisimas gracias, super crack!! estaba tan concentrado en que era de otro lugar el error que no me habia dado cuenta en algo tan simple... agradezco de todo corazon tu ayuda!
